# How to draw this IFS cantor set with labels?

Tags: python, fractals, zelle-graphics

I am using the Zelle graphics package in Python to draw the iterations of a cantor ternary like IFS (iterated function system) graph.
The iterated function system I want to draw is:

```
{R;x/9+1/6,2/3+x/9,x/9+1/3,x/9+5/6}
```

The following code is an imitation of what I found on the Internet. Is the code correct? How do I get each line segment to have a different color, and how do I label the points in each stage?

```
from graphics import *

def cantor_set(win,x,y,h,Len): 

    if Len < 2: return

    line = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x+Len, y))
    line.setWidth(20)
    line.draw(win)

    cantor_set(win,2*x+3,y+h,h,Len//18)
    cantor_set(win,2*x+12,y+h,h,Len//18)
    cantor_set(win,2*x+6,y+h,h,Len//18)
    cantor_set(win,2*x+15,y+h,h,Len//18)

def cantor_set_starter():
    Len = 790
    win = GraphWin("Cantor Set", 800, 200)
    c = cantor_set(win,5,20,50,790)
win.postscript(file = "can1.eps")
#win.getMouse()
#win.close()
cantor_set_starter()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two major types of errors in programming, *syntax* and *algorithm*.  Your program suffers from both.  We can fix your *syntax* errors fairly easily:

```
from graphics import *

def cantor_set(win, x, y, h, length):

    if length < 2:
        return

    line = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x + length, y))
    line.setWidth(20)
    line.draw(win)

    cantor_set(win, 2 * x + 3, y + h, h, length // 18)
    cantor_set(win, 2 * x + 12, y + h, h, length // 18)
    cantor_set(win, 2 * x + 6, y + h, h, length // 18)
    cantor_set(win, 2 * x + 15, y + h, h, length // 18)

def cantor_set_starter(length):
    cantor_set(win, 5, 20, 50, length)

win = GraphWin("Cantor Set", 800, 200)

cantor_set_starter(790)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

But since there are *algorithm* errors, it doesn't draw a cantor ternary-like graph.  To help you fix these, we need to know more about where you got the the iterated function system equation and other details.  If the goal is simply to draw a Cantor Set, we can modify your program to do so, mostly by throwing away code and adjusting the math on what's left:

```
from graphics import *

def cantor_set(win, x, y, height, length):

    if length < 2:
        return

    line = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x + length, y))
    line.setWidth(height / 2)
    line.draw(win)

    length /= 3

    cantor_set(win, x, y + height, height, length)
    cantor_set(win, x + 2 * length, y + height, height, length)

win = GraphWin("Cantor Set", 800, 300)

cantor_set(win, 5, 20, 50, 790)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

[image]